# Converting docx to html (color is lost)

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a series of pretty simple Word docs (docx format) - a few hundred of such files.

which I will need to import into a website and retain basic layout  - colors, indents, paragraphs etc (nothing too fancy, and no images etc).

But when I view the document as HTML (whether regular or filtered) it seems to lose the colors (at the very least).

What would be the best way to convert these to HTML while saving the basic layout and design? (preferably in the leanest HTML possible - I know how Word adds a lot of unnecessary code by default)

And then - Any ideas for converting in batch/bulk all these files, instead of one by one?

Attaching a link to a sample file (download link valid till 27/10): [Download link of DOCX file (wetransfer.com)](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/850bd160513931beb9d9ad013f3d916e20191020084959/df25f22fd85aa29037f108c667b7c18820191020084959/ccebaa)

Also - below, screen captures of WORD and HTML post-conversion

**HTML, exported from Word:**
https://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/rn5xkzLc/

**Word Version:** 
[image: Word Version]

**HTML post-conversion:** 
[image: HTML post-conversion]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [wordtohtml.net](https://wordtohtml.net/). If you want to see how it works in trial mode, convert it here then run the converted text in a second site: [codebeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/)

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but your colors will be retained when read by the proper view/display program (as the second link does).

GL!

_rod

Answer (score 0):

This online converter website should work: https://wordhtml.com/
Just paste in or upload your document and it will be converted to HTML(colour and formating is preserved)

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work. it removes ALL formatting (font and color included) on-paste. and it does not have an upload option.

Comment: @kneidels oh, sorry